# How to populate a Razor MVC 4 List from a List<string>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a get property which returns a list of string:

```
public List<string> CountryList 
{
    get
    {
        foreach (CultureInfo ci in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures & CultureTypes.NeutralCultures))
        {
            RegionInfo ri = new RegionInfo(ci.LCID);
            CountryList.Add(ri.EnglishName);
        }

        return CountryList;
    }
}
```

I want to create a bootstrap drop-down box and populate it with this list using the Razor engine.

Here is my attempt:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Country, model.CountryList, "-- Select Country --")
```

Comment: Read a tutorial on asp.net MVC and learn how to do it.

Comment: @ataravati i have and i really have tried so many methods, they're not working with me. I need some help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't want to include the code in your model. You should populate the CountryList in your Controller. Also, change your CountryList to a `List<SelectListItem>` like this:

```
public List<SelectListItem> CountryList { get; set; }
```

And, populate it in your controller action, like this:

```
foreach (CultureInfo ci in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures & CultureTypes.NeutralCultures))
{
    RegionInfo ri = new RegionInfo(ci.LCID);
    CountryList.Add(new SelectListItem 
    { 
        Text = ri.EnglishName, 
        Value = ri.EnglishName
    });
}
```

Then, here's what you'll have in your View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Country, model.CountryList, "-- Select Country --")
```

By the way, I'd suggest that you use the CountryCode in your Model as a property, instead of country name and change the code to populate your CountryList to this:

```
foreach (CultureInfo ci in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures & CultureTypes.NeutralCultures))
{
    RegionInfo ri = new RegionInfo(ci.LCID);
    CountryList.Add(new SelectListItem 
    { 
        Text = ri.EnglishName, 
        Value = ri.Name
    });
}
```

Finally, read more about asp.net MVC before starting to code.

Comment: Since `CountryList` is already `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, creating another identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from the first one is pointless extra overhead - its just `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Country, Model.CountryList, "-- Select Country --")`

Comment: Oh, sorry! That was a mistake. I fixed that.

Comment: Thank you, this is great. Yes i will be reading more about MVC today.

Comment: @ataravati I am having troubles passing the list from the controller to my view and i can not get it from my model

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a `CountryList` which is `List<string>` you can simpley do this in your View.

In your cshtml page write this in the code block

```
 @{
   var CountryList =  Model.CountryList.Select(x=> new SelectListItem{ Text = x, Value = x}).ToList();
  }
```

And then just change your dropdown code to

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Country, CountryList, "-- Select Country --")

// note that we are using the newly created variable
```

I know the logic must be in the controller end and not mix up in the View as it the goal of MVC, This is a workaround if at all you cant go back and clean up your controller or have some other issues due to which you can't take that approach.

Answer (score -1):

The second parameter of `DropdownListFor` is an `IEnumerable` of `SelectListItem`, and you're trying to pass a `List` of strings.

`Razor` needs a list of `SelectListItem`, so he can understand what is the value of each object in the collection and what is the text to show.

Doing this should work for you:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CountryList 
 {
    get
    {
        var _countryList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (CultureInfo ci in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures & CultureTypes.NeutralCultures))
        {
            RegionInfo ri = new RegionInfo(ci.LCID);

            var selectListItem = new SelectListItem();
            selectListItem.Value = ci.LCID.ToString(); //Value of the object, should be unique
            selectListItem.Text = ri.EnglishName; //Text that will be displayed

            _countryList.Add(selectListItem);
        }

        return _countryList;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not good practice to populate the list in the model. The list should be populated from the controller (outside of the model).